# libreoffice writer crash when hitting enter key with japanese input method

Tags: libreoffice, japanese

Being a japanese learner, I recently configured my ubuntu system so I can use a Japanese input method (the Anthy method).

I decided to create a document where I have a table containing 3 columns : a sub-table, a standard column and another sub-table.

When I write some Japanese kana in the middle column, and press the enter key, libreoffice writer systematically crashes. What's more troubling, it doesn't when I do the same on the left or right subtable. And I never encountered any similar problem with other applications.

Here's a screen shot of what I'm doing :
[my page layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyD9W.png)

Moreover, I can't see anything written on the log at ~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/uno_packages/cache/log.txt, and I don't see anything on the terminal right after the crash.

Comment: It depends on the X-Window system, Xfce has no problem when you select any of ibus/fcitx and Anthy or Mozc, but Unity and Gnome has some problems, I figured out Unity and Gnome3 16.04/18.04 LTS has less problems with **fcitx-mozc** for now. The sample shows me the typical 'floating window problem', perhaps you are at ibus engine with Anthy, no wonder it crushes.

Comment: Yes, I use ibus engine with Anthy, but I am on Xubuntu, so with Xfce's window system, so it normally wouldn't bug, if I understand correctly what you mean, right?

Comment: Normally, yes. But I haven't seen Xubuntu myself and never tried LibreOffice on Xfce. But anyway, since 18.04 ibus has some conflicts especially inline-Henkan, fcitx-mozc does always. The floating window Henkan-window is somewhat 20th century taste.